# xamarin forms VS - How to view sqlite3 DB from CMD - get proper location of local DB on android app?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, cmd, xamarin.android

Evening All,

Working my way through creating my first app using xamarin vs 2017. Have DB tables being created, and CRUD operations being performed in the code.

However, I would like to view the tables. I have found a clip showing how to view SQLite db from windows using command prompt:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXEZZ2JT3-k

and has worked, so by creating a folder on my desktop I can create a new sqlite3 db, with tables, and then view the tables and schema (please see below)...However this worked because I have the location of the db...How can I obtain the location from my app?...when creating the connection it uses the path:

```
/data/user/0/com.companyname.TestProjectXamarin/files/TestDB.db3;
```

**What do I need to add to the front of this to obtain the location**

Thank You
[image]

Comment: you will need to use adb to copy the file from Android to your desktop, then you can open it with whatever sqlite tool you want

Comment: ok thanks ill give it a go and let you know